# jade.compile returning a function

Tags: node.js, pug

I want to redo my blog but my code below seems to be returning `[function]` whenever I console.log it.  Yes it is the correct path, and it used to work before I updated jade but not anymore.

```
post.stub = jade.compile(
        fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/blog/' + p + '/stub.jade')
)
```

How do I fix this so that `console.log(post.stub)` will return my :markdown present in the jade file instead of `[function]` ?

Thanks in advance.

Updated answer:

```
 post.stub = jade.compile(
            fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/blog/' + p + '/stub.jade')
        )({})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how jade and all similar template systems work. There are 2 steps:

1. Convert a jade text template into a function (only needs to happen once per template)
2. Take a set of context data, run it through the compiled template function, and return the rendered string as HTML (happens every time you have unique context data)

So if your template doesn't need any context data, just invoke it with an empty object (probably null/undefined would also work fine):

```
post.stub = jade.compile(
        fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/blog/' + p + '/stub.jade')
)({})
```

See also [the jade javascript API docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a5).

Comment: Thanks man, Your example didn't actually work but you gave me the clue to make it work.  (You probably just typed wrong by accident)  Ill give you the answer.  Anyways if anyone was wondering the correct code looks as I added to my original post.

Comment: and why does jade return the function? why not use callbacks?

    var fn = jade.compile('string of jade', options);
    console.log('one');
    console.log(fn(locals));
    console.log('two');

wouldn't it be 'one', 'two' and then the html?

Comment: Ah yeah, I put my parens in the wrong place. Good catch. Answer edited. Returning a function is primarily a performance optimization as parsing the raw jade syntax is expensive and you want to be able to re-render the template potentially 100s or 1000s of times with different data (like records from a database), so you parse the raw jade once, convert it into an efficient javascript function, and then invoke that function 100s of times with different data.